# How to connect the Calculator GUI to the graph GUI?

Tags: python, graph, calculator

I want to connect calculator gui with function graph gui.
For example
if I clicked 'sinx' on the calculator, the graph(which is sine function) would be apear on graph gui.
How could I do?

1. Calculator GUI code

   from tkinter import *
       window = Tk()
       window.title("해대비주얼")
       ''
       top_row = Frame(window)
       top_row.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=N)
       display = Entry(top_row, width=35, bg="light blue")
       display.grid()

   ```
   num_pad = Frame(window)
   num_pad.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
   num_pad_list = [
       '7','8','9',
       '4','5','6',
       '1','2','3',
       '0','.','=']
   r = 0
   c = 0
   for btn_text in num_pad_list:
       def cmd(x=btn_text):
           click(x)
       Button(num_pad, text=btn_text, width=5, command=cmd).grid(row=r, column=c)
       c = c + 1
       if c > 2:
           c = 0
           r = r + 1




   operator = Frame(window)
   operator.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)
   operator_list = [
       '*','/',
       '+','-',
       '(',')',
       '^','C']
   r = 0
   c = 0
   for btn_text in operator_list:
       def cmd(x=btn_text):
           click(x)
       Button(operator, text=btn_text, width=5, command=cmd).grid(row=r, column=c)
       c = c + 1
       if c > 1:
           c = 0
           r = r + 1



   etc = Frame(window)
   etc.grid(row=50, column=0, sticky=S)
   etc_list = ['pi','sin','cos','x']
   r = 0
   c = 0
   for btn_text in etc_list:
       def cmd(x=btn_text):
           click(x)
       Button(etc, text=btn_text, width=5, command=cmd).grid(row=r, column=c)
       r = 0
       c = c + 1

   def click(key):
       if key == "=":
           try:
               if "^" in display.get():
                   n = display.get().split(sep="^")
                   result = str(float(n[0]) ** float(n[1]))
                   display.insert(END, " = " + result)
               else:
                   result = str(eval(display.get()))[0:10]
                   display.insert(END, " = " + result)
           except:
               display.insert(END, " --> Error!")
       elif key == "C":
           display.delete(0, END)
       elif key == etc_list[0]:
           import math
           display.insert(END, math.pi)
       else:
           display.insert(END, key)


   window.mainloop()
   ```

2.Graph GUI code

```
 from tkinter import *
    graph = Tk()
    graph.title("해대비주얼 그래프")
    ''
    graph.geometry("1000x700")
    ''
```